# adding two images using opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I need to extract L(illuminative component)from RGB frame and obtain the inverted illuminative image (L).
adding the inverted image to the original L image.

My question is how can i add two images (L channel of lab and inverted image)?
Which function can do that?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. You have 2 images and you want to get the Lightness from both images - that much is clear. But then you want to add the two Lightnesses together? Or invert them? Or add them and invert the sum and subtract it from one, or both maybe, original images?

Comment: I have one image , I wan to extract L (lightness ) and invert it .  Then add the inverted (L) with to the original extracted (L)

Comment: If you do `L + (255 - L)` you will end up with `255`, surely?

Comment: if you see this link may be it will be clear to you :                                                                                                                                                                                     http://postimg.org/image/in4de2ax9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think http://answers.opencv.org/question/81947 is your question. so i tried to revise it as far as i understand your question. hope it will help.

source :[image]

result  : [image]

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

void split_lab( Mat planes )
{
    Mat lab, blurredL;
    cvtColor( planes, lab, CV_BGR2Lab );

    vector <Mat> splits;
    split(lab, splits);

    medianBlur( splits[0], blurredL, 31);

    blurredL = 255 - blurredL;

    cvtColor( blurredL, blurredL, CV_GRAY2BGR );
    planes = planes + ( blurredL * 0.5 );

}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Mat src= imread( argv[1] );

    split_lab(src);
    imshow( "result", src );
    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1. is blurredL = 255 - blurredL;    same as  bitwise_not( blurredL, dst) ;          2.  planes = planes + ( blurredL * 0.5 );   why multiplied by 0.5                                 3.  planes = planes + ( blurredL * 0.5 );    same result if addWeighted  or cv::add() used ?  Thanks  @sturkmen

Comment: 1. yes

2. try planes = planes + blurredL ; you will see why ?

3. it is same cv::add()  not addWeighted

Comment: where did you get the method that you tried to implement? if you have a paper please share it.

Comment: THe method is in this paper (Blink detection robust to various facial poses)  called Illumination normalization    : http://docdro.id/69lb0gX

Comment: cvtColor( blurredL, blurredL, CV_GRAY2BGR );    why  blurredL is converted to BGR before addition ?

Comment: see [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga10ac1bfb180e2cfda1701d06c24fdbd6)